# How to read each number individually from lines when reading from a file

Tags: c++, list, file

Needing guidance on how to read numbers from a file and setting each individual number from the rows to set up functions

I have read through the file and was able to print out the numbers onto the screen, but I'm running into some understanding on how am I going to be able to print use on of those numbers for a specific function that I am wanting to use. For instance I have

```
string line;
while(getline(file,line)){
    cout<<line<<"\n";
}
/* What the file is and what it prints out onto the screen
  3 6
  2 3 2
  2 1 6
  2 1 4
  1 2 3
  1 1 2
  2 1 8
 */
```

For instance I want to use the **3** and **6** for a function such as

```
create_list(int x, int y){}
```

In other words each set set of numbers in each row will be representing input to some functions

Comment: Do you mean parsing the numbers out of each line once you've read it?

Comment: Open your C++ book to the chapter that explains how to use the `std::istringstream` class. After reading each line, use the read `std::string` to construct a `std::istringstream`, and use the formatted extraction operator to extract the individual numbers from the read line. Mission accomplished.

Comment: Which part exactly are you having a problem with? Reading the numbers? Calling the function? How are the numbers supposed to be passed to your function?

Comment: I'm wanting to read each number individually from every line

Comment: You can simply use the `>>` operator to read numbers from an `std::ifstream` (I assume that's what your `file` is) just like you can use it to read numbers from any `std::istream` in general…

Comment: What does all the numbers mean? Especially, how is the first line (containing `3` and `6`) related to the rest of the file? If those numbers are the number of columns and lines (respectively) then just read those using the normal `>>` operator, then create a `std::vector` of `std::vector` of `int` with the right dimensions, and in two nested `for` loops read the remaining data (also using `>>`) indexing your vector of vectors.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid simply posting a solution here. Note that it's not necessary and quite wasteful to first copy every line into a dynamically allocated string just so that you can then read the numbers out of there, when your numbers are originally already coming out of a perfectly fine `std::istream`. It seems to me that the main problem you're having here is figuring out whether a line has ended or not. Maybe just think for a moment about how you could detect that…

Answer (score 1):

**Parsing variable number of integers from input line**

It is not clear from the question what you are trying to do.  As mentioned in the comments, you can parse the file directory using the ifstream.  I am lazy and always parse files with `getline(<ifstream>, str)` and then parse the lines using an istringstream.  I make fewer mistakes this way.

One of the questions was why you have multiple line lengths.  No matter, I made up functions that were called depending on whether there were 1, 2, or 3 integers for each input line.

The great thing about parsing the input using a stream, is that the stream processor can parse ints, doubles, or whatever.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

int square(std::vector<int> &ints)
{
  return ints[0] * ints[0];
}

int rectangle(std::vector<int> &ints)
{
  return ints[0] * ints[1];
}

int volume(std::vector<int> &ints)
{
  return ints[0] * ints[1] * ints[2];
}

int main()
{

  std::ifstream file;
  file.open("example.txt");

  std::string str;
  while (getline(file, str)) {
    int parsed_int;
    std::vector<int> ints;
    int index = 0;

    std::stringstream stream(str);
    while (stream >> parsed_int) {
      ints.push_back(parsed_int);
      ++index;
    }

    int answer = 0;
    // index is the number of integers read on this line from the file
    switch (index) { 
      case 0:break;
      case 1:answer = square(ints);
        break;
      case 2:answer = rectangle(ints);
        break;
      case 3:answer = volume(ints);
        break;
      default:break;
    }
    std::cout << "Answer is " << answer << "\n";
  }
}
```